# Installed Kernel 3.2.4 in Natty Cannot remove 2.6.38-13

Tags: 11.04, kernel

Installed 3.2.4 from Oneric mainline and boots and runs everything perfectly. However cannot remove 2.6.38-13 without it claiming a broken package.

Have used synaptic to fix broken but still cannot remove.

Comment: did you build any custom packages or kernel modules that depend there?

Comment: Well, Natty was installed with whatever kernel comes with it. The machine has seen dist-update many times. The last kernel installed before 3.2.4 was 2.6.38-13 generic pae. I have not built any packages but I have installed many applications.

Comment: My guess is that one of the applications built a kernel module...virtualbox for example

Comment: If that were the case when I installed the new kernel wouldn't it be overwritten?

Comment: No.  A new kernel doesn't pull in modules built by packages.  Just because the module still works just means there wasn't an API change that caused it to crash yet.  Some might not complain by depending on linux-headers instead of a version.  It's something you take responsibility for when you start using things that require kernel modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one-liner and see if it fixes it for you:

```
apt-cache rdepends packagename
```

Comment: $ apt-cache rdepends linux
linux
Reverse Depends:
 |zramswap-enabler
I can see this may be the issue